# Using timers correctly in swift with MVC design pattern

Tags: swift, timer

I am completely new to Swift. I'm creating an app that functions like a stopwatch. The timer was working previously when all the code was in one file, I then tried to implement the MVC design pattern to clean up my code and now I can't get the timer to work inside my model file inside a struct. The problematic line is

```
fastTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
```

The first error I get is 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'FastBrain' but then as I try and fix this I get further different errors.

**How do I correctly start this timer?**

Code from working version where everything was in the ViewController file:

```
fastTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            
            // Update the elapsed time variable
            self?.elapsedTime += timer.timeInterval
            
            // Format the elapsed time as a stopwatch time
            //calculate values for timer label for next run

            let hours = Int(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0) / 3600 % 60
            let minutes = Int(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0) / 60 % 60
            let seconds = Int(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0) % 60
            
            //if fast is completed don't recalculate progress bar
            if self?.progressBar.progress ?? 0.0 >= 1.0 {
                self?.progressBar.progress = 1
            } else {
                //calculate value for progress bar
                self?.progressBar.progress =  Float(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0.0) / self!.goalFastTimeSeconds
            }
            
            // Update the label with the formatted time
            self?.timeElapsedLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
        })
        
        // Update the button text as we've started fast
        sender.setTitle("Finish Fast", for: .normal)
        
    } //timer loop stops here
```

I then put it into a struct file and I can't get rid of the errors on the timer line to move ahead.

Here is what I have in my model struct file:

```
import Foundation

struct FastBrain {
    
    var goalFastTimeHours = 1
    var goalFastTimeSeconds: Float = 3600
    var progress: Float = 0.0
    var fastTimer: Timer?
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = 0
    let startDate: Date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    var hours = 0
    var minutes = 0
    var seconds = 0
   
 
    mutating func startFast(){
        
        //start the timer - except it won't :-(
        fastTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            
            // Update the elapsed time variable
            elapsedTime += fastTimer?.timeInterval ?? 0.0
            
            //calculate values for timer label for next run
            hours = Int(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0 ) / 3600 % 60
            minutes = Int(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0 ) / 60 % 60
            seconds = Int(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0) % 60
          
            
            //if fast is completed don't recalculate progress bar
            if progress >= 1.0 {
                progress = 1
            } else {
                //calculate value for progress bar
                progress =  Float(self?.elapsedTime ?? 0.0 ) / (self?.goalFastTimeSeconds ?? 0)
            }
            //How do I call this function from here?
            //  updateUIDuringFast()
            
        })//block ends here
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `FastBrain` a class instead of a struct.

Comment: Also, don't count timer ticks for a stopwatch - A `Timer` isn't very accurate.  Read https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f - It's SwiftUI rather than UIKit but the fundamentals of tracking elapsed time using a `Date` and running the Timer at a higher rate apply.

Comment: Thank you both. @Paulw11 that article is exactly what I needed! Thanks so much.